# Using two motors in Scratch 3 with Lego EV3

Tags: lego-mindstorms, mit-scratch, lego-mindstorms-ev3

Scratch 3 seems to only have commands to start one motor at a time for X seconds. With two motors, one at each wheel, how do I tell both motors to go for a while so the robot moves forward?

Answer (score 1):

Put two "received [message name] message" events and attach a motor control block to each of them.